# how to print entire row of a particular string by using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

my file name is data.txt

#### employer_name          salary            designation

kundan                    20000               accounts
amit                      15000               fielder
chandan                   25000              assi-hr
....
....
.....

in this way i had created a file. i was looking for by using awk can i
print employer name , salary  and desigination in one line when i want to search a particular employeer data..

does awk reads excel files?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Excel files"*? If your file is a text file (which I assume it is because you have called it `data.txt`) it is not an Excel file. Excel files normally end in `.xls` or `.xlsx`

Comment: wrt `does awk reads excel files?` - see [how-do-i-use-awk-under-cygwin-to-print-fields-from-an-excel-spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805123/how-do-i-use-awk-under-cygwin-to-print-fields-from-an-excel-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

If your data file really is space separated sequence of data, something like this would work:

```
$ cat >> find.awk
BEGIN {
    RS=" "
} 
NR%3==1 {
    name=$1
} 
name==find { 
    printf "%s%s", $1, (NR%3 ? OFS : ORS)
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -f find.awk -v find="kundan" data.txt
kundan 20000 accounts
```

If your data were:

```
kundan
20000
accounts
...
```

just remove the `BEGIN` block. If your data were:

```
kundan 20000 accounts
amit 15000 fielder
...
```

use `grep ^kundan data.txt` or `awk -v find="kundan" '$1==find' data.txt` but the latter is longer to write.

AWK does not read Excel files per se. You can export your Excel files to CSV files and run AWK against them. AWK likes CSV files. :D

Comment: thank you for your help. but while run the above command

[root@paramount Desktop]#awk -f find.awk -v find="kundan" data.txt
kundan (#output while i was expecting entire that row to be print)

currently i was doing
[root@paramount Desktop]#vi search
echo " enter the employer name :"
read input
grep -w "$input" data.txt

[root@paramount Desktop]#./search
kundan 20000 accounts