# How to use xarg (or awk or sed) to run each line of screen output as a command exactly as displayed?

Tags: awk, xargs

*** ADDENDUM: I use Windows10, GNUWIN32 and Cygwin64 ***

Suppose I have the following screen output:

```
command1 
command2 
command3
```

The desired result is each line shown above is executed as a command immediately after it is displayed on screen.

```
command1
command2
command2
```

I have read this post which explains how to insert "echo" before each line of screen output.
[How to apply shell command to each line of a command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711001/how-to-apply-shell-command-to-each-line-of-a-command-output)
It does this:

```
ls -1 | xargs -L1 echo
```

What I have done for the time being is insert "run.bat" infront of each line. The result is the following lines are executed:

```
run.bat command1
run.bat command2
run.bat command3
```

The content of run.bat is this:

```
%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

It works. But this work-around seems unncessarily long.

**How do I use xarg (or awk or sed) to take each line of screen output as an individual command, and run it immediately and exactly as it is displayed on screen please?**

PS: I also do not want to redirect & save all screen output into a separate batchfile first, and then execute all lines that way. I would like each line of screen output to be execute exactly as a command, exactly as it is displayed and immediately after the line is displayed (I do not need to add any prefix or suffixed to the lines; just execute each line exactly as displayed on screen).

Thanks.

Comment: What shell are the commands written in? The use of `awk` and `xargs` suggests it is probably bash, but the name `run.bat` and the syntax `%1 %2` etc suggest windows batch file. Please edit your question to clarify the language of the commands.

Comment: Hi user0000001, I use Windows10, GNUWIN32 and Cygwin64.  The shell is cmd.exe under Windows 10.

Comment: If you're using cygwin then the shell should be bash, not cmd.exe. Please verify if you're using bash or cmd.exe.

Comment: If you're really trying to call a Unix command provided by Cygwin from a Windows "batch" file (or `cmd.exe`?), maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878922/gawk-3-1-6-1-on-windows-7-x64-pro-gets-0-return-code-using-system-even-on-fail/58879683#58879683 will give you some ideas but just calling the Unix tools from  a bash shell started by cygwin.exe would obviously be simpler.

Comment: You may be right Ed. The shell should be bash if I'm using GNUWIN/Cygwin. 
I tested out this command:
C:\Windows\system32>dir | c:\gnuwin32\bin\xargs -n1 bash -c 'echo "$@"; "$@"'
and this:
C:\Windows\system32>dir | c:\cygwin64\bin\xargs -n1 bash -c 'echo "$@"; "$@"'
They produced this error message respectively:
c:\gnuwin32\bin\xargs: bash: No such file or directory
c:\cygwin64\bin\xargs: bash: No such file or directory
The expected error is the following:
XXXXX is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Where XXXXX is each line of dir

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your output to this `xargs` command line:

```bash
... | xargs -n1 bash -c 'echo "$@"; "$@"' _
```

This `xargs` calles `bash -c` script that echoes each line on stdout and then executes it.

Comment: Yes I answered this question too with something similar, but then I realized that OP is probably using windows batch, and not `bash`.