# How to convert .xls or .xlxs file to csv file without any plugins or tools using Unix command

Tags: unix

I have to convert `.xls` or `.xlxs` file to .csv file without using plugins or tools using Unix Command

Is their any way to do this ?

I Tried to do like this below ...But not working

Change the characterSet code from .xls file to UTF-8 encoding

Then create file again with extension change

```
cp temp.xls temp.csv
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38805123/1745001, including the other answers provided as links under the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to realise that an `*.xls` file is a zipped directory structure (just unzip such a file, using Winzip or 7-zip). The unzipping can also be done using UNIX commands.

But what then? The directory structure is quite complicated to understand, and in order to create a script or a program which can do this (without using any external tools) is a tremendous work, so I'd propose you, either to use external tools anyway, or to make sure the files you receive already are CSV format.